# viewport user-scalable não funciona no safari ajuda

Tags: html, viewport

Olá,
Eu coloquei um meta no meu site, só que no safari ele não funciona.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100px, user-scalable=0;">
```

uso isso para a tela se ajustar, testei no android, no chrome no mozila, e fica certo, porem entro no safari ele não pega o width=1100px;